# Discord bot with wolfram alpha api not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, wolframalpha

So I'm making a discord bot that uses the wolfram alpha api to answer questions. I am using the wolframalpha module in python and this is my code:

```
import discord
import wolframalpha

bot = discord.Client()
token = "XXX"
app_id = "XXX"
client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f"Logged in as {bot.user}")

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
  if(not msg.content.startswith("w,")):
    return
  
  question = msg.content[2:len(msg.content)]
  res = client.query(question)

  em = discord.Embed(title=str(msg.author), description = next(res.results).text)

  await msg.channel.send(embed=em)

bot.run(token)
```

It is intended to respond to discord messages of the form `w, question`. For example `w, how many inches in a foot?`. And I want it to reply with an embed.

But when I run it, it shows this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 19, in on_message
    res = client.query(question)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wolframalpha/__init__.py", line 127, in query
    doc = xmltodict.parse(resp, postprocessor=Document.make
Logged in as Paradøx#3063
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 21, in on_message
    res = client.query(question)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wolframalpha/__init__.py", line 127, in query
    doc = xmltodict.parse(resp, postprocessor=Document.make)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xmltodict.py", line 325, in parse
    parser.ParseFile(xml_input)
  File "../Modules/pyexpat.c", line 461, in EndElement
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xmltodict.py", line 141, in endElement
    self.item = self.push_data(self.item, name, item)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xmltodict.py", line 157, in push_data
    result = self.postprocessor(self.path, key, data)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wolframalpha/__init__.py", line 174, in make
    value = cls._find_cls(key)(value)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wolframalpha/__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
    self._handle_error()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wolframalpha/__init__.py", line 141, in _handle_error
    raise Exception(template.format(**self))
Exception: Error 1: Invalid appid
```

Since it says invalid appid at the end I rechecked the app id and it was correct.